# Why does the Berry Phase of π cause anti localisation in Dirac fermions?

Tags: topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am learning about the theory of topological insulators and one point that puzzles me is the following:

The Berry Phase aqcuired by forming a closed loop on a Dirac cones is π. The argument that I do not understand is that "the time reversed scattering paths interfere destructively and cause an anti-localisation effect". I do know that TRS causes the dirac fermion behavior but where does the time reversed path come into play here? I don't understand the interaction between the two in this case.